# Confused about CSS Absolute Positioning, Floating, Centering

Tags: css, css-float, css-position, centering

I've read a number or articles and tutorials on CSS all of which cover Absolute Position, Floating, etc. I thought I understood it well, and usually can use both and achieve desired design. But here and there I run into a situation  where I don't understand what is happening with an element absolutely positioned or floating and can't make it behave the way I need. So something is missing in my understanding of how these CSS rules work.

Here is a specific example. I'm re-skining  a WP theme for a non-profit organization. In their design they want the navigation centered. Seems like nothing should be easier. But so far I have completely failed at achieving that.

The link to the site is here:  http://justaddsolutions.com/d_build/

Comment: The width-attribute of an img should be specified without % (or any other measurement). But what is it that you are trying to centre? Most things look centred already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this.

**First one**

1. Wrap the navigation in a full width wrapper.
2. Set text-align: center; for the wrapper.
3. Set display: inline-block; or inline, for the navigation bar.
4. Done!

**Second one**

If you know the exact width of the navigation bar, you can try this solution:

1. Set position: absolute; for the navigation.
2. Set left: 50%; for the navigation.
3. Set margin-left to the negative width of the navigation divided by 2.
4. Done!

I am sure there are more ways to achieve this, but these two work great for me!
You should not use floating for center alignment, only for left and right.

Comment: Thank you so much! This totally worked.